# Как вывести 20 строк функции main, с помощью objdump на Windows?

Tags: mingw

Встретил такую вот команду: objdump -D a.out | grep -A20 main.:
Но команда grep, как я понимаю для, консоли Linux.
Есть альтернатива для консоли Windows чтобы выполнить эту команду(кажется, вывести 20 строк функции main)?

Answer (score 0):

Команда выводит 20 строк после того, как найдет main.:

Есть 2 варианта

1. поставить cygwin и получить виндовые версии кучи линус-программ
2. поставить виртуалочку с линуксом и получить все это нативно (мой выбор)